# AWS S3 Java API MultipleFileDownload add worker

Tags: java, swing, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download

I'm writing a swing GUI for a program using AWS S3 java SDK; I am using a MultipleFileDownload naed download and when it starts downloading I have to add:

```
 download.waitForCompletion();
```

this is a blocking call so even if I addeded a listener to update a progress bar status (JProgressBar)

```
 download.addProgressListener(createProgressListener(download));
```

the progressbar won't change status until the download process has succesfully ended.

Is there any way to add a 2nd worker or thread to update the progress bar while downloading ?

Comment: Don't block the Swing thread (aka Event Dispatcher Thread - EDT). Use [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) instead.

Comment: In particular, it's perfectly OK to block in your implementation of `doInBackground()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  so if I got it, I should execute the download in a background thread? or the ProgressBar update? Coudl you please provide an example of SwingWorker and how to use the background thread to implement download? Should the progress listener be in the main thread while the download happen in a background thread?